# Merge field syntax in email templates for Campaign Members

Tags: email-template, campaign-member, merge-field

I'm trying to create a basic text email template to use in a workflow rule that will be sent out when a Campaign Member is created. I have read [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=merge_fields_email_templates.htm&language=en) that there are differences in how the syntax should work for the Campaign and CampaignMember objects, but the documentation seems incomplete. In my most recent attempt, I tried:

```
{!CampaignMember.Account}   // Blank. Was hoping for the Contact's account name.
{!CampaignMember.Campaign}  // Worked. Provided the Campaign's name
{!CampaignMember.Name}      // Blank. Was hoping for the Contact's name.
{!CampaignMember.Link}      // Link to Campaign Member. I ultimately want a link to the contact.
```

Does anyone know what the proper merge field syntax should be for Campaign Members?

Comment: I got the Contact's name with: `{!CampaignMember.Contact}`

Comment: I got the Account name with: `{!CampaignMember.CompanyOrAccount}`

Comment: I got the ContactId with: `{!CampaignMember.ContactId}`, and I guess I can use this to build the link, but it would be nice to have a more direct way to do it.